# jQuery Autocomplete to accept matches with speacial characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following setup. A autocomplete function that is working well. I have found a function to remove special characters too, it seems to work but I am not able to do it what I need.

What I exactly need is to match autocomplete results with & without special characters. So for example in the code below the first element in `availableTags` is `Ábelová`. What I need is to modify this so that the autocomplete matches `Ábelová` also when the user types `Abelova`.

Can anyone help?

```
bdiak = "áäčďéěíĺľňóô öŕšťúů üýřžÁÄČĎÉĚÍĹĽŇÓÔ ÖŔŠŤÚŮ ÜÝŘŽ"; 
sdiak = "aacdeeillnoo orstuu uyrzAACDEEILLNOO ORSTUU UYRZ"; 
function bezdiak(form) 
{ 
    tx = ""; 
    txt = form; 
    for(p = 0; p < txt.length; p++) 
    { 
        if (sdiak.indexOf(txt.charAt(p)) != -1) 
        { 
            tx += bdiak.charAt(sdiak.indexOf(txt.charAt(p))); 
        } 
        else 
        {
            tx += txt.charAt(p); 
        }
    } 
    return tx; 
} 

$(function () {
    var availableTags = [
        { label: "Ábelová,Lučenec,Banskobystrický kraj", id: "1" },
        { label: "Abovce,Rimavská Sobota,Banskobystrický kraj", id: "2" }
    ];

    $("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, response) { 
        var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term); 
        var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + re, "i" ); 
        response($.grep( bezdiak(availableTags), function(item){ 
        return matcher.test(item.label); 
        }) ); 
    },
    minLength: 2,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        $("#kraj").val(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to work with accent folding method. http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#folding

there's fully list of special characters for accent folding:

```
var accentMap = { "ẚ": "a", "Á": "a", "á": "a", "À": "a", "à": "a", "Ă": "a", "ă": "a", "Ắ": "a", "ắ": "a", "Ằ": "a", "ằ": "a", "Ẵ": "a", "ẵ": "a", "Ẳ": "a", "ẳ": "a", "Â": "a", "â": "a", "Ấ": "a", "ấ": "a", "Ầ": "a", "ầ": "a", "Ẫ": "a", "ẫ": "a", "Ẩ": "a", "ẩ": "a", "Ǎ": "a", "ǎ": "a", "Å": "a", "å": "a", "Ǻ": "a", "ǻ": "a", "Ä": "a", "ä": "a", "Ǟ": "a", "ǟ": "a", "Ã": "a", "ã": "a", "Ȧ": "a", "ȧ": "a", "Ǡ": "a", "ǡ": "a", "Ą": "a", "ą": "a", "Ā": "a", "ā": "a", "Ả": "a", "ả": "a", "Ȁ": "a", "ȁ": "a", "Ȃ": "a", "ȃ": "a", "Ạ": "a", "ạ": "a", "Ặ": "a", "ặ": "a", "Ậ": "a", "ậ": "a", "Ḁ": "a", "ḁ": "a", "Ⱥ": "a", "ⱥ": "a", "Ǽ": "a", "ǽ": "a", "Ǣ": "a", "ǣ": "a", "Ḃ": "b", "ḃ": "b", "Ḅ": "b", "ḅ": "b", "Ḇ": "b", "ḇ": "b", "Ƀ": "b", "ƀ": "b", "ᵬ": "b", "Ɓ": "b", "ɓ": "b", "Ƃ": "b", "ƃ": "b", "Ć": "c", "ć": "c", "Ĉ": "c", "ĉ": "c", "Č": "c", "č": "c", "Ċ": "c", "ċ": "c", "Ç": "c", "ç": "c", "Ḉ": "c", "ḉ": "c", "Ȼ": "c", "ȼ": "c", "Ƈ": "c", "ƈ": "c", "ɕ": "c", "Ď": "d", "ď": "d", "Ḋ": "d", "ḋ": "d", "Ḑ": "d", "ḑ": "d", "Ḍ": "d", "ḍ": "d", "Ḓ": "d", "ḓ": "d", "Ḏ": "d", "ḏ": "d", "Đ": "d", "đ": "d", "ᵭ": "d", "Ɖ": "d", "ɖ": "d", "Ɗ": "d", "ɗ": "d", "Ƌ": "d", "ƌ": "d", "ȡ": "d", "ð": "d", "É": "e", "Ə": "e", "Ǝ": "e", "ǝ": "e", "é": "e", "È": "e", "è": "e", "Ĕ": "e", "ĕ": "e", "Ê": "e", "ê": "e", "Ế": "e", "ế": "e", "Ề": "e", "ề": "e", "Ễ": "e", "ễ": "e", "Ể": "e", "ể": "e", "Ě": "e", "ě": "e", "Ë": "e", "ë": "e", "Ẽ": "e", "ẽ": "e", "Ė": "e", "ė": "e", "Ȩ": "e", "ȩ": "e", "Ḝ": "e", "ḝ": "e", "Ę": "e", "ę": "e", "Ē": "e", "ē": "e", "Ḗ": "e", "ḗ": "e", "Ḕ": "e", "ḕ": "e", "Ẻ": "e", "ẻ": "e", "Ȅ": "e", "ȅ": "e", "Ȇ": "e", "ȇ": "e", "Ẹ": "e", "ẹ": "e", "Ệ": "e", "ệ": "e", "Ḙ": "e", "ḙ": "e", "Ḛ": "e", "ḛ": "e", "Ɇ": "e", "ɇ": "e", "ɚ": "e", "ɝ": "e", "Ḟ": "f", "ḟ": "f", "ᵮ": "f", "Ƒ": "f", "ƒ": "f", "Ǵ": "g", "ǵ": "g", "Ğ": "g", "ğ": "g", "Ĝ": "g", "ĝ": "g", "Ǧ": "g", "ǧ": "g", "Ġ": "g", "ġ": "g", "Ģ": "g", "ģ": "g", "Ḡ": "g", "ḡ": "g", "Ǥ": "g", "ǥ": "g", "Ɠ": "g", "ɠ": "g", "Ĥ": "h", "ĥ": "h", "Ȟ": "h", "ȟ": "h", "Ḧ": "h", "ḧ": "h", "Ḣ": "h", "ḣ": "h", "Ḩ": "h", "ḩ": "h", "Ḥ": "h", "ḥ": "h", "Ḫ": "h", "ḫ": "h", H: "h", "̱": "h", "ẖ": "h", "Ħ": "h", "ħ": "h", "Ⱨ": "h", "ⱨ": "h", "Í": "i", "í": "i", "Ì": "i", "ì": "i", "Ĭ": "i", "ĭ": "i", "Î": "i", "î": "i", "Ǐ": "i", "ǐ": "i", "Ï": "i", "ï": "i", "Ḯ": "i", "ḯ": "i", "Ĩ": "i", "ĩ": "i", "İ": "i", i: "i", "Į": "i", "ı": "i", "į": "i", "Ī": "i", "ī": "i", "Ỉ": "i", "ỉ": "i", "Ȉ": "i", "ȉ": "i", "Ȋ": "i", "ȋ": "i", "Ị": "i", "ị": "i", "Ḭ": "i", "ḭ": "i", I: "i", "ı": "i", "Ɨ": "i", "ɨ": "i", "Ĵ": "j", "ĵ": "j", J: "j", "̌": "j", "ǰ": "j", "ȷ": "j", "Ɉ": "j", "ɉ": "j", "ʝ": "j", "ɟ": "j", "ʄ": "j", "Ḱ": "k", "ḱ": "k", "Ǩ": "k", "ǩ": "k", "Ķ": "k", "ķ": "k", "Ḳ": "k", "ḳ": "k", "Ḵ": "k", "ḵ": "k", "Ƙ": "k", "ƙ": "k", "Ⱪ": "k", "ⱪ": "k", "Ĺ": "a", "ĺ": "l", "Ľ": "l", "ľ": "l", "Ļ": "l", "ļ": "l", "Ḷ": "l", "ḷ": "l", "Ḹ": "l", "ḹ": "l", "Ḽ": "l", "ḽ": "l", "Ḻ": "l", "ḻ": "l", "Ł": "l", "ł": "l", "Ł": "l", "̣": "l", "ł": "l", "̣": "l", "Ŀ": "l", "ŀ": "l", "Ƚ": "l", "ƚ": "l", "Ⱡ": "l", "ⱡ": "l", "Ɫ": "l", "ɫ": "l", "ɬ": "l", "ɭ": "l", "ȴ": "l", "Ḿ": "m", "ḿ": "m", "Ṁ": "m", "ṁ": "m", "Ṃ": "m", "ṃ": "m", "ɱ": "m", "Ń": "n", "ń": "n", "Ǹ": "n", "ǹ": "n", "Ň": "n", "ň": "n", "Ñ": "n", "ñ": "n", "Ṅ": "n", "ṅ": "n", "Ņ": "n", "ņ": "n", "Ṇ": "n", "ṇ": "n", "Ṋ": "n", "ṋ": "n", "Ṉ": "n", "ṉ": "n", "Ɲ": "n", "ɲ": "n", "Ƞ": "n", "ƞ": "n", "ɳ": "n", "ȵ": "n", N: "n", "̈": "n", n: "n", "̈": "n", "Ó": "o", "ó": "o", "Ò": "o", "ò": "o", "Ŏ": "o", "ŏ": "o", "Ô": "o", "ô": "o", "Ố": "o", "ố": "o", "Ồ": "o", "ồ": "o", "Ỗ": "o", "ỗ": "o", "Ổ": "o", "ổ": "o", "Ǒ": "o", "ǒ": "o", "Ö": "o", "ö": "o", "Ȫ": "o", "ȫ": "o", "Ő": "o", "ő": "o", "Õ": "o", "õ": "o", "Ṍ": "o", "ṍ": "o", "Ṏ": "o", "ṏ": "o", "Ȭ": "o", "ȭ": "o", "Ȯ": "o", "ȯ": "o", "Ȱ": "o", "ȱ": "o", "Ø": "o", "ø": "o", "Ǿ": "o", "ǿ": "o", "Ǫ": "o", "ǫ": "o", "Ǭ": "o", "ǭ": "o", "Ō": "o", "ō": "o", "Ṓ": "o", "ṓ": "o", "Ṑ": "o", "ṑ": "o", "Ỏ": "o", "ỏ": "o", "Ȍ": "o", "ȍ": "o", "Ȏ": "o", "ȏ": "o", "Ơ": "o", "ơ": "o", "Ớ": "o", "ớ": "o", "Ờ": "o", "ờ": "o", "Ỡ": "o", "ỡ": "o", "Ở": "o", "ở": "o", "Ợ": "o", "ợ": "o", "Ọ": "o", "ọ": "o", "Ộ": "o", "ộ": "o", "Ɵ": "o", "ɵ": "o", "Ṕ": "p", "ṕ": "p", "Ṗ": "p", "ṗ": "p", "Ᵽ": "p", "Ƥ": "p", "ƥ": "p", P: "p", "̃": "p", p: "p", "̃": "p", "ʠ": "q", "Ɋ": "q", "ɋ": "q", "Ŕ": "r", "ŕ": "r", "Ř": "r", "ř": "r", "Ṙ": "r", "ṙ": "r", "Ŗ": "r", "ŗ": "r", "Ȑ": "r", "ȑ": "r", "Ȓ": "r", "ȓ": "r", "Ṛ": "r", "ṛ": "r", "Ṝ": "r", "ṝ": "r", "Ṟ": "r", "ṟ": "r", "Ɍ": "r", "ɍ": "r", "ᵲ": "r", "ɼ": "r", "Ɽ": "r", "ɽ": "r", "ɾ": "r", "ᵳ": "r", "ß": "s", "Ś": "s", "ś": "s", "Ṥ": "s", "ṥ": "s", "Ŝ": "s", "ŝ": "s", "Š": "s", "š": "s", "Ṧ": "s", "ṧ": "s", "Ṡ": "s", "ṡ": "s", "ẛ": "s", "Ş": "s", "ş": "s", "Ṣ": "s", "ṣ": "s", "Ṩ": "s", "ṩ": "s", "Ș": "s", "ș": "s", "ʂ": "s", S: "s", "̩": "s", s: "s", "̩": "s", "Þ": "t", "þ": "t", "Ť": "t", "ť": "t", T: "t", "̈": "t", "ẗ": "t", "Ṫ": "t", "ṫ": "t", "Ţ": "t", "ţ": "t", "Ṭ": "t", "ṭ": "t", "Ț": "t", "ț": "t", "Ṱ": "t", "ṱ": "t", "Ṯ": "t", "ṯ": "t", "Ŧ": "t", "ŧ": "t", "Ⱦ": "t", "ⱦ": "t", "ᵵ": "t", "ƫ": "t", "Ƭ": "t", "ƭ": "t", "Ʈ": "t", "ʈ": "t", "ȶ": "t", "Ú": "u", "ú": "u", "Ù": "u", "ù": "u", "Ŭ": "u", "ŭ": "u", "Û": "u", "û": "u", "Ǔ": "u", "ǔ": "u", "Ů": "u", "ů": "u", "Ü": "u", "ü": "u", "Ǘ": "u", "ǘ": "u", "Ǜ": "u", "ǜ": "u", "Ǚ": "u", "ǚ": "u", "Ǖ": "u", "ǖ": "u", "Ű": "u", "ű": "u", "Ũ": "u", "ũ": "u", "Ṹ": "u", "ṹ": "u", "Ų": "u", "ų": "u", "Ū": "u", "ū": "u", "Ṻ": "u", "ṻ": "u", "Ủ": "u", "ủ": "u", "Ȕ": "u", "ȕ": "u", "Ȗ": "u", "ȗ": "u", "Ư": "u", "ư": "u", "Ứ": "u", "ứ": "u", "Ừ": "u", "ừ": "u", "Ữ": "u", "ữ": "u", "Ử": "u", "ử": "u", "Ự": "u", "ự": "u", "Ụ": "u", "ụ": "u", "Ṳ": "u", "ṳ": "u", "Ṷ": "u", "ṷ": "u", "Ṵ": "u", "ṵ": "u", "Ʉ": "u", "ʉ": "u", "Ṽ": "v", "ṽ": "v", "Ṿ": "v", "ṿ": "v", "Ʋ": "v", "ʋ": "v", "Ẃ": "w", "ẃ": "w", "Ẁ": "w", "ẁ": "w", "Ŵ": "w", "ŵ": "w", W: "w", "̊": "w", "ẘ": "w", "Ẅ": "w", "ẅ": "w", "Ẇ": "w", "ẇ": "w", "Ẉ": "w", "ẉ": "w", "Ẍ": "x", "ẍ": "x", "Ẋ": "x", "ẋ": "x", "Ý": "y", "ý": "y", "Ỳ": "y", "ỳ": "y", "Ŷ": "y", "ŷ": "y", Y: "y", "̊": "y", "ẙ": "y", "Ÿ": "y", "ÿ": "y", "Ỹ": "y", "ỹ": "y", "Ẏ": "y", "ẏ": "y", "Ȳ": "y", "ȳ": "y", "Ỷ": "y", "ỷ": "y", "Ỵ": "y", "ỵ": "y", "ʏ": "y", "Ɏ": "y", "ɏ": "y", "Ƴ": "y", "ƴ": "y", "Ź": "z", "ź": "z", "Ẑ": "z", "ẑ": "z", "Ž": "z", "ž": "z", "Ż": "z", "ż": "z", "Ẓ": "z", "ẓ": "z", "Ẕ": "z", "ẕ": "z", "Ƶ": "z", "ƶ": "z", "Ȥ": "z", "ȥ": "z", "ʐ": "z", "ʑ": "z", "Ⱬ": "z", "ⱬ": "z", "Ǯ": "z", "ǯ": "z", "ƺ": "z", "２": "2", "６": "6", "Ｂ": "B", "Ｆ": "F", "Ｊ": "J", "Ｎ": "N", "Ｒ": "R", "Ｖ": "V", "Ｚ": "Z", "ｂ": "b", "ｆ": "f", "ｊ": "j", "ｎ": "n", "ｒ": "r", "ｖ": "v", "ｚ": "z", "１": "1", "５": "5", "９": "9", "Ａ": "A", "Ｅ": "E", "Ｉ": "I", "Ｍ": "M", "Ｑ": "Q", "Ｕ": "U", "Ｙ": "Y", "ａ": "a", "ｅ": "e", "ｉ": "i", "ｍ": "m", "ｑ": "q", "ｕ": "u", "ｙ": "y", "０": "0", "４": "4", "８": "8", "Ｄ": "D", "Ｈ": "H", "Ｌ": "L", "Ｐ": "P", "Ｔ": "T", "Ｘ": "X", "ｄ": "d", "ｈ": "h", "ｌ": "l", "ｐ": "p", "ｔ": "t", "ｘ": "x", "３": "3", "７": "7", "Ｃ": "C", "Ｇ": "G", "Ｋ": "K", "Ｏ": "O", "Ｓ": "S", "Ｗ": "W", "ｃ": "c", "ｇ": "g", "ｋ": "k", "ｏ": "o", "ｓ": "s", "ｗ": "w" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have built on fgokalps solution to make diacritic conversion available throughout the site for all autocomplete widgets:

```
var accentMap = {as per fgokalps post};
var normalize = function (term) {
    var ret = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < term.length; i++) {
        ret += accentMap[ term.charAt(i) ] || term.charAt(i);
    }
    return ret;
};
$.extend($.ui.autocomplete, {

    escapeRegex: function (value) {
        return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
    },

    filter: function (array, term) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(term), "i");
        return $.grep(array, function (value) {
            value = value.label || value.value || value;
            return matcher.test(value) || matcher.test(normalize(value));
        });
    }
});
```